# Best Brush for Tinning Flux

Tags: plumbing, copper, copper-pipe

Looking for a recommendation for a good brush to use with tinning flux. The basic synthetic brushes used with regular water soluble flux work just fine. But tinning flux is a lot thicker, pastier, almost like a sealing wax.

Is there a good harder-bristled brush available?

Comment: Warm it in a pan of hot water : )

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stainless-steel bristle brush, which would be harder bristles and won't corrode too fast.

Answer (score 0):

The flux I buy has a brush attached to the lid and it seems to outlast the flux every time.

I use it for both the pipe end **and** the fitting and I clean both before fluxing. To clean - even "new" pipe and "new" fittings straight out of the bag I use the green scotchbrite kitchen style cleaning pad. Takes off all bu the worst corrosion and makes sure even "clean new" fittings don't have an almost invisible layer of corrosion on them. That way I have very few failed joints.